# How can I easily get metrics emitted and shown on the toit console

Tags: toit

I have some custom metrics I would like to emit (e.g. the current battery voltage)

Is there an easy way to get these shown on the toit console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no way of showing custom metrics in the console.

An alternative would be to use the Humio integration. All logs from any device will be sent to humio which you can find at [humio.toit.io](https://humio.toit.io).

A simple approach would be to make a log statement with the battery voltage an create a humio dashboard with a graph showing that. Note that the toit log module has a `tag` mechanism which would be useful for values in this scenario.